# R string manipulation

Tags: r, string, truncate

I have a csv file the first column has a long string. How do I truncate string to limit to "NineOneTwo" or "NineOneTwo" but not the rest?

The first 3 lines are like:

```
HEADERLINE,Time,Name,Owner,Dummy1,Dummy2,Number
NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; 
Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 
06:04:25,DR,A,0.000000,0.000000,1472.233
NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; 
Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:14:25,SO,A,0.000000,0.000000,1550.388
NineOneTwo [912; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; 
Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:19:25,LM,A,0.000000,0.000000,1439.232
```

Rscript:

```
dat <- read.csv(csvfile, header = TRUE)
abc <- filter( dat, Number > 1000 )
hinum <- select( abc,Time,Number,HEADERLINE)
print (hinum)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `filter` and `select` are not base R functions. Please include the names of any packages you are using in your post.

Comment: please can you rephrase your question? Am sorry it is not clear

Comment: You want to keep only the first word from the first column, which should be either 'Nineoneone', or 'Nineonetwo'? Try this `substr(x[[1]], 1, 10)`? or `sub(' .+$', '', x[[1]])`

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr with `mutate`:

```
read.table(text = "HEADERLINE,Time,Name,Owner,Dummy1,Dummy2,Number
    NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:04:25,DR,A,0.000000,0.000000,1472.233
    NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:14:25,SO,A,0.000000,0.000000,1550.388
    NineOneTwo [912; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:19:25,LM,A,0.000000,0.000000,1439.232", 
    sep=",", header=T) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(HEADERLINE = substr(HEADERLINE, 1, 10))
```

or, if the length of the word can vary, split each HEADLINE by the space and take the first word:

```
read.table(text = "HEADERLINE,Time,Name,Owner,Dummy1,Dummy2,Number
    NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:04:25,DR,A,0.000000,0.000000,1472.233
    NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:14:25,SO,A,0.000000,0.000000,1550.388
    NineOneTwo [912; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:19:25,LM,A,0.000000,0.000000,1439.232", 
    sep=",", header=T) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(HEADERLINE = as.character(HEADERLINE), 
              HEADERLINE = sapply(strsplit(HEADERLINE, " "), function(x) return(x[1])))
```

Output:

```
  HEADERLINE                Time Name Owner Dummy1 Dummy2   Number
1 NineOneOne 07/19/2017 06:04:25   DR     A      0      0 1472.233
2 NineOneOne 07/19/2017 06:14:25   SO     A      0      0 1550.388
3 NineOneTwo 07/19/2017 06:19:25   LM     A      0      0 1439.232
```

Comment: Alternative to `substr()`, splitting on whitespace and selecting the first element: `strsplit(HEADERLINE, " ")[[1]][1]`.

Comment: funny, I was editing my answer just while you wrote that, because I got the same idea :) good!

Comment: Or also could use `sub()` as in the comment above - might be nicer than `sapply()`

Answer (score 0):

Not being much of a `plyr` user, here's a base approach

```
abc <- read.csv(text = "HEADERLINE,Time,Name,Owner,Dummy1,Dummy2,Number
    NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:04:25,DR,A,0.000000,0.000000,1472.233
    NineOneOne [911; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:14:25,SO,A,0.000000,0.000000,1550.388
    NineOneTwo [912; OUHOST2 - sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; Limi69sumo.6973; - sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973; NJ sumo.6973; sumo.6973; sumo.6973],07/19/2017 06:19:25,LM,A,0.000000,0.000000,1439.232", 
    header=TRUE)

abc$HEADERLINE <- sapply(strsplit(trimws(abc$HEADERLINE), " "), '[', 1)
str(abc)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  7 variables:
#  $ HEADERLINE: chr  "NineOneOne" "NineOneOne" "NineOneTwo"
#  $ Time      : Factor w/ 3 levels "07/19/2017 06:04:25",..: 1 2 3
#  $ Name      : Factor w/ 3 levels "DR","LM","SO": 1 3 2
#  $ Owner     : Factor w/ 1 level "A": 1 1 1
#  $ Dummy1    : num  0 0 0
#  $ Dummy2    : num  0 0 0
#  $ Number    : num  1472 1550 1439
```